# plpgsql - pgAdmin 4 doesn't show RAISE messages (ex., NOTICE)

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin-4

I recently installed pgAdmin 4 after using pgAdmin III for a long time. I noticed that nothing was showing up under Messages after running a plpgsql function with RAISE NOTICE. I went to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html and tried doing:

```
set client_min_messages = 'NOTICE';
```

Also tried setting to various levels of DEBUG, but still nothing showed up. The NOTICEs will appear when connected using pgAdmin III, so I figured there's just some difference between the two that I'm not seeing.

In case somebody asks, I just tried one of the example functions from Postgres to test this out:

```
CREATE FUNCTION somefunc() RETURNS integer AS $$
<< outerblock >>
DECLARE
    quantity integer := 30;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Quantity here is %', quantity;  -- Prints 30
    quantity := 50;
    --
    -- Create a subblock
    --
    DECLARE
        quantity integer := 80;
        BEGIN
            RAISE NOTICE 'Quantity here is %', quantity;  -- Prints 80
            RAISE NOTICE 'Outer quantity here is %', outerblock.quantity;  -- Prints 50
    END;

    RAISE NOTICE 'Quantity here is %', quantity;  -- Prints 50

    RETURN quantity;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In pgAdmin III, the expected notices are raised:

> NOTICE:  Quantity here is 30
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function somefunc() line 6 at RAISE
>   NOTICE:  Quantity here is 80
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function somefunc() line 14 at RAISE
>   NOTICE:  Outer quantity here is 50
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function somefunc() line 15 at RAISE
>   NOTICE:  Quantity here is 50
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function somefunc() line 18 at RAISE
>
> Total query runtime: 14 ms.
>   1 row retrieved.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or answers!

Comment: I can confirm that this issue is with version 1.1 on osx. I find that there are other issues as well on the osx version (inability to filter non-active dbs when connecting to Heroku). I believe this question would be better served by logging it as an issue with their team.

Answer (score 3):

I am able to see it Properly, Did you check in "Messages" Tab ?

Refer given screenshots.

[image]

[image]

> UPDATE

Recently, They fixed some bug related to displaying messages in pgAdmin4.
So it would be available in **pgAdmin4 version 1.7**.

Ref: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/2555

Comment: Hi n33rma, I did indeed check the Messages tab and nothing shows up. Only runtime and "1 rows retrieved". Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/ptdWrXZ.png

Comment: That is strange even with your function, I'm getting proper output. Screenshot: 
http://imgur.com/a/5A2Ef

Comment: (If that helps) I am using latest version of pgAdmin4 (Download: https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin3/pgadmin4/v1.1/windows/ ) and hopefully v1.2 will be out soon with many more bug fixes.

Comment: This issue has been fixed.

Upgrade to pgAdmin4 version 1.3. https://www.pgadmin.org/download/

Comment: This issue may have been fixed in v1.3, but it is also occurring in v1.4.

Comment: Nice, solved my problem by updating from an old installer to a new one