# Want to call a Stored Proc that generates sequence based on arg

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I'd like to write a Postgres Stored Proc (cannot be a function) that accepts two args:
seq_name and current ID.

If the ID has a value then the SP should return the value.
If the ID is NULL then the code should call the sequence name passed in as arg and return that nextval.

I'd then like an example of calling that within PGAdmin. I thin it's do/begin/call but I don't know how to get that returned ID and display it.

Hope that makes sense.
Tx

Was thinking it would be something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_generate_seq ( s_seq_name VARCHAR(255), i_id INOUT INT )
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  CASE id_gen 
    WHEN i_id IS NULL THEN
      SELECT nextval.s_seq_name
    INTO i_id ;
  END id_gen
END $$

do
$$
declare i_val int ;
begin
call sp_generate_seq ( 'foo_seq', i_val);  -- Should return next sequence value since i_val is NULL
raise notice '%', i_val ;
-- I hope that calling again should return the same value since nextval will not be called
call sp_generate_seq ( 'foo_seq', i_val);  
raise notice '%', i_val ;
end
$$
```

Comment: If you want to return a single value, use a function. Stored procedures aren't meant for that. Additionally `nextval()` is a **function**, you can call it using `nextval.some_sequence` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html

Comment: I'm calling from an external app that only allows Stored Procs to be called - not Functions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `PL/pgSQL`, plain `SQL` will be [enough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24755468/5298879). You can also replace your `CASE` with [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) which returns the first non-null value in the argument list.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_generate_seq(s_seq_name text, i_id INOUT bigint)
LANGUAGE sql
AS '
  select coalesce(i_id,nextval(s_seq_name));
';
--CREATE PROCEDURE
```

If you're not seeing the output of [`RAISE`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41991037/5298879), you can insert the results of your tests to a table and check it after the anonymous function block.

```sql
create table sp_generate_seq_test (attempt serial, output bigint);
--CREATE TABLE
do
$$
declare 
    i_val bigint;
begin
    call sp_generate_seq ( 'test_sequence', i_val);  -- Should return next sequence value since i_val is NULL
    raise notice '%', i_val ;
    insert into sp_generate_seq_test(output) values (i_val);
-- I hope that calling again should return the same value since nextval will not be called
    call sp_generate_seq ( 'test_sequence', i_val);  
    raise notice '%', i_val ;
    insert into sp_generate_seq_test(output) values (i_val);
end
$$;
--NOTICE:  1
--NOTICE:  1
--DO
table sp_generate_seq_test;
-- attempt | output
-----------+--------
--       1 |      1
--       2 |      1
--(2 rows)
```